# Isometric camera with THREE.js

Tags: three.js

How can I set the camera angle to something like the [isometric projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection)?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To get an isometric view, you can use an `OrthographicCamera`. You then need to set the camera's orientation properly. There are two ways to do that:

Method 1 - use `camera.lookAt()`

```
const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
const d = 20;
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( - d * aspect, d * aspect, d, - d, 1, 1000 );

camera.position.set( 20, 20, 20 ); // all components equal
camera.lookAt( scene.position ); // or the origin
```

method 2 - set the x-component of `camera.rotation`

```
camera.position.set( 20, 20, 20 );
camera.rotation.order = 'YXZ';
camera.rotation.y = - Math.PI / 4;
camera.rotation.x = Math.atan( - 1 / Math.sqrt( 2 ) );
```

[image: Isometric View Using Orthographic Camera]

EDIT: updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vkjew52q/

three.js r.146

Comment: If you set the camera position to 100 on the Z axis then you will maintain will prevent clipping the grid with the near clip plane on the camera. In order to keep the same isometric view though you will also need to update the X Y positions to match.
Line 44
`camera.position.set( 100, 100, 100 );`