# Emulate isometric rendering properly in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, isometric

I'm currently working on a small game, just to kill time - I have been doing most of the rendering with CSS3 transforms, etc
[image: old code])
(the code of this version is [here](https://github.com/EXio4/shadow-hunter/commit/ad78b058ef913d93f133133ed3529813e5a1ad9c))

So, now I'm trying to rewrite this into a more powerful way with the goal of allowing more stuff on the virtual world (efficient light, weather, shadows, day-night cycles, etc) in a less CPU-intensive way..

Anyway, the problem is my vast **non**-knowledge of 3D graphics, so with some trial and error I've managed to get
[image: new code])
But still far from what I have currently achieved with CSS transforms, at this moment, [this is what I have so far (code-wise)](https://github.com/EXio4/shadow-hunter/tree/d40e8cf997ce64552b29820169898e087bf5ff76), when it comes to the rewrite

The code which handles the game logic, is still the same, and I'm working on wrappers over three.js, these are in src/render, in particular, [Camera](https://github.com/EXio4/shadow-hunter/blob/d40e8cf997ce64552b29820169898e087bf5ff76/src/render/Camera.js#L17-L19):

```
  const camera = this.props.ctx.renderer.camera
  camera.position.set( lookAt[0]+20, 20, lookAt[1]+20)
  camera.lookAt(lookAt[0], 0, lookAt[1])
```

and in [Renderer](https://github.com/EXio4/shadow-hunter/blob/d40e8cf997ce64552b29820169898e087bf5ff76/src/render/Renderer.js#L53-L57), I've got:

```
  let d = 15
  this.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-d, d, d, -d, 0.1, 1000)

  this.camera.position.set( 30, 30, 30 ); // all components equal
  this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0))
```

(d=20 still looks pretty different)

The code there is basically taken verbatim [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450588/isometric-camera-with-three-js)

My current goal is basically to get a similar render to what I currently have with CSS3 transforms, using three.js.

**Fixed it with manthrax's help**

**Code which solves this:**

```
cube.rotation.x = Math.PI * -0.5
```

**On the tiles**

Comment: There is a CSSRenderer in three that does what yr describing :) but if you already have assets n stuff, I'd humbly suggest going straight to 3d/webgl!

Comment: I'm trying to steer away from CSS so I can potentially use shaders in the future, this is more of a future-proof rewrite
(currently, the tiles are just plain colors, no textures yet)

Comment: I help moderate a three.js dev slack... Feel free to drop in and we can help walk you through the transition. :)

https://join.slack.com/t/threejs/shared_invite/enQtMzYxMzczODM2OTgxLWE5OTU4OTYxZTZlODk1ZGNjODIyMDZlODM4ZmUyMzNiOWIxMmFjNTYwOTc4MjU0ZmNiODk5MzZiMGJhMTkzZWI

Comment: There is also the concept of "skewing" the camera matrix which is the equivalent of a real world "tilt/shift" lens. When naively setting an orthographic camera to achieve this i think you're going to get some height shortening. You could skew this matrix and get a height of 1 to always be 1, or even do something like "cavalier projection".

Comment: can you give me any resources for this?